# radiobutton checked on condition in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, radio-button

I have the following fields:

```
            <label>Company Type:</label>
            <label for="primary"><input onclick="javascript: $('#sec').hide('slow');$('#primary_company').find('option:first').attr('selected','selected');" type="radio" runat="server" name="companyType" id="primary" />Primary</label>
            <label for="secondary"><input onclick="javascript: $('#sec').show('slow');" type="radio" runat="server" name="companyType" id="secondary" />Secondary</label>
            <div id="sec">
            <fieldset>
            <label for="primary_company">Primary Company:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("primary_company", Model.SelectPrimaryCompanies, "** Select Primary Company **") %>
            </fieldset>
```

If there is a primary_company, then the secondary radio button should be selected.
If there is no primary_company, then the primary radio button should be selected.

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#primary_company').val().length > 0) {
            $('#secondary').attr({ checked: true });
        }
        else {
            $('#primary').attr('checked', true );
            $('#sec').hide();
        }
```

The sec div hides and shows properly, but a radio button is never selected.
I've tried `.attr('checked', 'checked')` and `.attr({ checked: true })` and `.attr('checked', true)` but nothing is ever selected.

**EDIT**
I've now tried `.attr('checked', 'true')`
Could there be something wrong with my ids maybe?  I'm stuck.

Comment: You're close, just a few more permutations. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `runat="server"` on the input tags for the radio buttons.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is:

$('#secondary').attr('checked','true');

Comment: More formally, `.attr('checked', 'checked');`